# xquery - compare xsi:type with different namespace prefix

Tags: xquery

```
declare namespace xf = "http://example.com"
declare namespace my = "http://example.com"
```

How can I compare something like

```
<1 xsi:type="xf:myDef">
<1 xsi:type="my:myDef">
```

These 2 elements above are equals, however comparing the attribute as string it fails.
How can compare both prefix and type, resolving the URI?

Thanks

Comment: Formally, the two elements (BTW, an element name cannot start with a digit!!!) aren't equal -- the `xsi:type` attributes do have different string values. What you are saying is that there exists an interpretation, in which the two elements mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Why should they not be the same? They have different prefix, but they point to the same namespace URI.

Comment: Alessandro: You give one possible *interpretation* of the XML document. In reality, these are two different XML documents that happen to have the same interpretation/meaning. In the W3 XML specification there is no special interpretation for values of attributes (with the exception of the few global attributes in the XML namespace, such as `xml:space`, `xml:lang`, etc. The standard XPath 2.0 `deep-equal()` function considers equal elements or attributes *names*, that are in the same namespace regardless of the prefix. Not so for attribute *values*. XML happened before XSD and is unaware of it.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above:

> In the W3 XML specification there is no special interpretation for values of attributes (with the exception of the few global attributes in the XML namespace, such as xml:space, xml:lang, etc. The standard XPath 2.0 deep-equal() function considers equal elements or attributes names that are in the same namespace regardless of the prefix. Not so for attribute values. XML happened before XSD and is unaware of it.